# MySQL get query from query

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query that gets me the `meta_key` equal to `_cnote_module_number` and the `post_id` equal to `$mod_id`.

But now how do i add onto that query after i get the `post_id = '$mod_id'` to look at the result and find the `meta_value` (which is a number) and than to look back into `meta_key` equal to `_cnote_module_number` and get the `meta_value` thats greater than the `meta_value` from the first result.

```
$query = ( "SELECT * FROM postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_cnote_module_number' AND post_id = '$mod_id'" );
```

EDIT

I have 2 tables the first is postmeta, with..

```
-------------------------------------
 post_id  |  meta_key  |  meta_value
-------------------------------------
    10    |   jason    |     1
    49    |   cnote    |     3
    56    |   cnote    |     2
    97    |   cnote    |     7
```

The second is usermeta with..

```
-----------
  mod_id  
-----------
    10    
    49    
    67
```

I want to make sure that `postmeta.meta_key = 'cnote'` and `usermeta.mod_id` is equal to `postmeta.post_id`. Than whichever ID was equivalent i want to get the `postmeta.meta_value` and than find the first number greater than that value.

In this example i would like the result to be the 4th row from the postmeta

Comment: Ah: " the first number greater than that value" was an important thing to have in your question. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` a table to itself by giving it two different names. For example, the following would return **all** meta_values where the `B` table's meta_value was greater than the `A` table's meta_value:

```
SELECT B.meta_value
FROM postmeta A
JOIN postmeta B
ON (    B.meta_value > A.meta_value
    AND A.meta_key = B.meta_key)
WHERE A.meta_key = 'cnote'
AND A.post_id = '$mod_id'
```

But for your specific question, we want the **next** meta_value. That's even easier; since you are only wanting to return one row, you can take the MIN of the meta_values from above:

```
SELECT MIN(B.meta_value)
FROM postmeta A
JOIN postmeta B
ON (    B.meta_value > A.meta_value
    AND A.meta_key = B.meta_key)
WHERE A.meta_key = 'cnote'
AND A.post_id = '$mod_id'
```

If you want to get a query that returns **all** pairs of meta_values where A.meta_value immediately precedes B.meta_value, we can do that too; let me know.

Comment: Alright, i updated the question. its a little confusing, but i hope my example helps!

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer but left in most of the original query. Let me know if it doesn't work and you can't make it work; I didn't spend enough time looking at your table structure to make much sense of it.